# Variable no asigned error in a index of a bidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, variables, indexing

I was trying to do a code Where i need use a bidimensional array and when i get it the index it say the variable isn't asigned

```js
let vertices = [
  [1, 10],
  [2, 20],
  [3, 30],
  [1, 10],
];

for (let i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
  console.log(vertices[i][1]);
  console.log(vertices[i + 1][0]);
}
```

Comment: With `vertices[i + 1]` you're asking the code to return a value from an element that doesn't exist,

Comment: But how can i do it works?

Comment: The 0 is what get the error for get it clear because when i remove the second index it works

Comment: You have an array with a length of 4 which means indexes that run from 0 to 3. When you reach the last index 3 you're asking the code to log the data in `i + 1` _but that array doesn't exist_. What output from your code are you expecting?